# no run on server of maven web proj in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven, configuration

I got some maven project from git. I ran maven build and succeed build. Then I want to run on tomcat server the project but I can't see the run configuration. Some guys told me that convert the project to dynamic web module facet. but when I converted the project to faceted form, so many errors appeared, and eclipse changed the project directories. I installed "me2WTP" plugins but i'm not sure it's working well..
can anyone know the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out [Tomcat Maven Plugin](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat7-maven-plugin/). Set up your configuration and deploy with goal `tomcat7:deploy`. It takes a little while to configure but it works.

If you are just doing quick tests copy/paste the compiled .WAR into the tomcat\webapps folder.

In case you really need to integrate both maven and eclipse on that project please update your question with the link for the sample app you are using so we can check it out.

For your own projects created with m2eclipse within Eclipse the archetypes already allow you for both maven compile and Eclipse's plug-in deploy on Tomcat, but builds are independant. This helps you develop the views that dont require app or server restart.